# Can't add foreign key with alter table query

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to add a foreign key to my table (oc_booking) but when I do the alter table query it returns "ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint" and I don't know why.

I tried using SQL (terminal) and HeidiSQL (a tool similar to MySQL Workbench).

This is the reference table (oc_user):

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_group_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username      | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password      | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| salt          | varchar(9)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| firstname     | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname      | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email         | varchar(96)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| image         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| code          | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip            | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status        | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_added    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is the table where I want to add a foreign key constraint (oc_booking):

```
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| appointment_id | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| id_supplier    | int(11)   | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| id_user        | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| date           | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

And this is my query:

```
ALTER TABLE oc_booking ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES oc_user(`user_id`);
```

Comment: You need to give the foreign key a name and `CONSTRAINT` keyword... `ALTER TABLE oc_booking ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY FK_NAME (id_user) REFERENCES oc_user(user_id);`

Comment: Same problem: ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: @LucaDiBello note that both the tables should be **InnoDB**. FK constraint works only this engine.

Comment: Problem fixed. Thank you very much @MadhurBhaiya, I was struggling for 2 hours!

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & base table initialization. PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar. Show as much as possible that constituent subexpressions are OK.